# How to align cards to the center with the same size?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align to the center in Oracle Apex cards by using the static content. My issue is that the alignment is not correct and the card sizes are not equal.

My HTML code:

```
<head>
    <style>
        .card {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            transition: 0.3s;
            width: 15%;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        .card:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        .container {
            padding: 12px 18px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="card"><img src="ex1" alt="ex1" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
        <h4>
            <p style="text-align:center;">
                <font size="2">
                   <a href="ex1 website" target="_blank">
                        <b>ex1</b>
                    </a>
                </font>
            </p>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <img src="ex2" alt="ex2" style="width:100%"/>
    <div class="container">
        <h4>
            <p style="text-align:center;">
                <font size="2">
                    <a href="ex2 website" target="_blank">
                        <b>ex2</b>
                    </a>
                </font>
            </p>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Issue illustration:

[image: result vs expected]

Comment: consider line breaking your code...

Comment: If you want the items to have space on their left/right sides, use `justify-content: space-around;` instead of `justify-content: center;`

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55826963/3013279)

Answer (score 1):

Create one div outer of the "card" and use below CSS:

```
.card{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: it will not work as per required result.

Answer (score 0):

add cards inside flex-container

```
<div class="flex-container">
 <div class="card"></div>
 <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

and add this to your CSS

```
<style>
.flex-container{display: flex;justify-content: space-around;background:#fff;}
</style>
```

Comment: This will only horizontally align the items; they will not be in the centre vertically.

Comment: Try adding `vertical-align: middle;`.

Comment: you have to add `align-self:center;` to card. it will resolve the issue. check my answer above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cards container should be:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

**align-items: stretch** will make cards to have the same height.

**padding** will add space to the top and bottom of container. Basically it will dictate the height of each cards.

Comment: it will not work as per required result. please do practical for same.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes, either you can give properties to `body` but that will effect on every page so add an outer `div`.

```css
html{
height: 100%;
}
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
min-height:100%;
}
.card-outer{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.card {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            transition: 0.3s;
            width: 15%;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 10px;
            align-self: center;
        }

        .card:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        .container {
            padding: 12px 18px;
        }
```

```html
<head>
    <style>
        
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="card-outer">
    <div class="card"><img src="ex1" alt="ex1" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
        <h4>
            <p style="text-align:center;">
                <font size="2">
                   <a href="ex1 website" target="_blank">
                        <b>ex1</b>
                    </a>
                </font>
            </p>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <img src="ex2" alt="ex2" style="width:100%"/>
    <div class="container">
        <h4>
            <p style="text-align:center;">
                <font size="2">
                    <a href="ex2 website" target="_blank">
                        <b>ex2</b>
                    </a>
                </font>
            </p>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```